# Pinescript - Cannot call 'plot' with 'series'=series[bool]

Tags: pine-script

I am the basic of basic coders, so excuse the redundancy and formatting. I have a script that works in V3, but I have to update it to V4 in order to publish.

I am attempting to show a green bar when the price is above all EMAs and red bar when price is below all EMAS.

The error states plot series should be type series[float] and not series[bool], but I cannot figure out how to write this in any other manner. I tried to create an if statement with the conditions, then plot, but that hasn't worked either.

Script:

```
study(title="Price above/below EMA", shorttitle="BuySellEMA", overlay=false)
len = input(9, minval=1, title="Length") 
lent = input(20, minval=1, title="Length")
lentt = input(50, minval=1, title="Length")
lenttt = input(100, minval=1, title="Length")
lentttt = input(200, minval=1, title="Length")

src = input(close, title="Source")
out = ema(src, len)
outt = ema(src, lent)
outtt = ema(src, lentt)
outttt = ema(src, lenttt)
outtttt = ema(src, lentttt)


plot(((close >= out) and (close >= outt) and (close >= outtt) and (close >= outttt) and         (close >= outtttt)), title="Buy", style=columns, color=lime)
plot(((close < out) and (close < outt) and (close < outtt) and (close < outttt) and (close < outtttt)), title="Buy", style=columns, color=red)
```

Error:

Compilation failed, reason: line 32: Cannot call 'plot' with 'series'=series[bool]. The argument should be of type: series[float];
line 34: Cannot call 'plot' with 'series'=series[bool]. The argument should be of type: series[float]

Comment: Please, always inlcude the `//@version=X` line in your examples (with whatever version you chose) so when people are copypasting your code, it will immediately reproduce the issue you are asking help about.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 100 instead of condition so it can be series, and you can use the condition in color to set it as lime/red or na

```
//@version=4
study(title="Price above/below EMA", shorttitle="BuySellEMA", overlay=false)
len = input(9, minval=1, title="Length") 
lent = input(20, minval=1, title="Length")
lentt = input(50, minval=1, title="Length")
lenttt = input(100, minval=1, title="Length")
lentttt = input(200, minval=1, title="Length")

src = input(close, title="Source")
out = ema(src, len)
outt = ema(src, lent)
outtt = ema(src, lentt)
outttt = ema(src, lenttt)
outtttt = ema(src, lentttt)


plot(close, title="Buy", style=plot.style_columns, color=((close >= out) and (close >= outt) and (close >= outtt) and (close >= outttt) and (close >= outtttt))?color.lime:na)
plot(close, title="Buy", style=plot.style_columns, color=((close < out) and (close < outt) and (close < outtt) and (close < outttt) and (close < outtttt))?color.red:na)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the error message is that yes, `plot()` can only display a numeric value and a boolean is not a numeric value.

You can, however, convert the boolean to a 0 and 1 with a ternary operator:

```
boolean_value           = condition          //this will be True or False
boolean_value_to_number = condition ? 1 : 0  //True will be 1 and False will be 0
```

To answer the generic problem you have, I suggest you explore `plotchar()`.

`plotchar()` can put a character or a text above or below a candle based on a condition (it is best used with `overlay = true`) and mark your candles appropriately.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
//@version=4
study(title="Price above/below EMA", shorttitle="BuySellEMA", overlay=true)
len = input(9, minval=1, title="Length") 
lent = input(20, minval=1, title="Length")
lentt = input(50, minval=1, title="Length")
lenttt = input(100, minval=1, title="Length")
lentttt = input(200, minval=1, title="Length")

src = input(close, title="Source")
out = ema(src, len)
outt = ema(src, lent)
outtt = ema(src, lentt)
outttt = ema(src, lenttt)
outtttt = ema(src, lentttt)

plotchar(series = ((close >= out) and (close >= outt) and (close >= outtt) and (close >= outttt) and (close >= outtttt)), title = "buy", char = "B", location = location.abovebar, color = color.green, size = size.tiny)
plotchar(series = ((close < out) and (close < outt) and (close < outtt) and (close < outttt) and (close < outtttt)), title = "sell", char = "S", location = location.belowbar, color = color.red, size = size.tiny)
```